# GRASS function r.fill.dir not working on specific DEMs

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, depression-filling

I'm using QGIS. The function `r.fill.dir` is not working on a few DEMs I'm working with. With other DEMs, it works. I attached the log report and one of the troublesome DEMs. You can see my QGIS specifications on the header lines of log report.

Checking a successful log report I detected the problem starts after the line:

*C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>r.fill.dir input=rast_61e9d7802b7e846* ...(it continues)

After this line, the successful one prints: *Reading input elevation raster map...* This is missing with the problematic DEMs. See below snippets of the logs. I italicized the last line where both trials are the same.

**Not successful case log portion**

> Importing raster map <rast_61e9d8c403a2f47>...
>
> 0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
>
> C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>g.region n=45.375885 s=45.249075
> e=-72.49909500000001 w=-72.750915 res=8.999999999999823e-05
>
> *C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>r.fill.dir input=rast_61e9d8c403a2f47
> format="grass" output=output91ca3ed354994c30b9f661dddf49e5e9
> direction=direction91ca3ed354994c30b9f661dddf49e5e9
> areas=areas91ca3ed354994c30b9f661dddf49e5e9 --overwrite*
>
> C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>g.region
> raster=output91ca3ed354994c30b9f661dddf49e5e9
>
> ERROR: Raster map <output91ca3ed354994c30b9f661dddf49e5e9 not found

**Succesful case log portion**

> Importing raster map <rast_61e9d7802b7e846>...
>
> 0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
>
> C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>g.region n=45.500895 s=45.374085
> e=-72.749115 w=-73.000935 res=8.999999999999823e-05
>
> *C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>r.fill.dir input=rast_61e9d7802b7e846
> format="grass" output=outputd4c609e519f242b7b70cf0bad02bd5c9
> direction=directiond4c609e519f242b7b70cf0bad02bd5c9
> areas=areasd4c609e519f242b7b70cf0bad02bd5c9 --overwrite*
>
> Reading input elevation raster map...
>
> 0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
>
> Filling sinks...
>
> Determining flow directions for ambiguous cases...
>
> Found 248 unresolved areas
>
> Repeat to get the final directions...
>
> Found 31 unresolved areas
>
> Writing output raster maps...
>
> 0..6..12..18..24..30..36..42..48..54..60..66..72..78..84..90..96..100
>
> C:\Users\ramoslem\Documents>g.region
> raster=outputd4c609e519f242b7b70cf0bad02bd5c9

I haven't overcome this. Any comment?

The supporting files (log and DEM) are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17nAz2L8TPhjHg_TY8ahzFLGCg0ENfc-H?usp=sharing).

Comment: Both error and success messages should be **text**, in the body of the question. This makes them legible on all devices and allows others to search for your issue.

Comment: Done it, Vince. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the "problematic" DEM?

Comment: I provided the link to both the DEM and the log.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17nAz2L8TPhjHg_TY8ahzFLGCg0ENfc-H?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your DEM file and opened it in QGIS 3.22. Then I ran `r.fill.dir` on it (setting as the input region the full map).

The result looks like this - no error appeared:

[image: Result of r.fill.dir run on DEM]

Comment: I installed QGIS 3.22.1 on a different PC. It didn't work for me; same errors.